# Using new Azure portal for Point-To-Site Connection

Tags: azure, vpn, gateway

I have successfully set up a connection between my PC and my azure virtual network using the 'Classic' virtual network.  I'm trying to upgrade now to use the new portal and the new virtual network template, but I'm stuck.  For connection types, there seems to be a new 'VNet-to-VNet' connection, the site-to-site connection and 'ExpressRoute'.

What is the analog in the new portal for setting up a connection between a single PC and the virtual network?  Any walkthroughs or blogs covering the subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point to site in ARM is only supported through Powershell right now, not in the portal.  The walkthrough can be found here: [Configure Point to Site Connection in RM using Powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/)

Note that, as per [Azure App Service Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/), there are some notable exceptions to what you can't do with this kind of VPN connection:

> There are some things that VNET Integration does not support including:
>   • mounting a drive
>   • AD integration
>   • NetBios
>   • private site access

Comment: Has anyone actually used the network set up using the article you posted?  I can get RDP and PING to work, but network shares don't work.

Comment: Yes - but you can't mount drives over this connection - I didn't know that was one of your requirements.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/ for restrictions - just edited my answer to include that reference.

Comment: Those are some pretty serious restrictions.  Thanks for the post, at least I won't beat myself up trying to mount a drive over a P2S VPN.